# How can I produce a small stamp on each image on my site

Tags: php, image, watermark, stamp

i work in lamp environment .
i search script that know to take a image , that user upload to my site.
and make from this image , new image that contain the real image with small stamp on the top corner.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your best bet would be to [look here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php) it is an ideal script provided by the PHP.net user guide. Just make sure that you have the GD library installed

Answer (score 1):

You'd want a watermark which can be [accomplished with GD](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/watermark-images-php/)

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is "watermarking". There are tools out there to do this, a lot of image manipulation packages have this feature.

A search for this might lead you to something useful.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these PHP tutorials:

- [Using imagecopymerge() to create a translucent watermark](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php)
- [Adding watermarks to images using alpha channels](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php)